# How to make C program

Tags: c

How do I make a program in Python that takes an integer as input and prints it as a string?

Fore example, input : 77 -> output : seventy-seven

Answer (score 0):

at first you should get input number length

for e.g (input->length) :

75 -> 2| 175 -> 3 | 9635 -> 4

then you should process it like this :

if length is 2 , first digit will be sth between twenty - ninety and the second will be sth between one - nine

if number just has 1 digit it will be sth between zero - nine

if number has 3 digit , 1st digit (from left) should be number + Thousand

for e.g : nine thousand and process to end

i hope i can explain what i want to say

Answer (score 0):

Use an already available package i.e. https://pypi.org/project/num2words/

```
>>> from num2words import num2words
>>> num2words(42)
forty-two
>>> num2words(42, to='ordinal')
forty-second
>>> num2words(42, lang='fr')
quarante-deux
```

**OR** write your own code to do this using dictionary matching (would probably be a good start).